# how to visualize feature map of CNN for tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, tensorboard

I want to see the convoluation result of all the kernals. Another say, I want to see the low level and hight level features of a CNN model. How can do this with tensorflow? Any example for that?

Here is a example:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this blog will help you. Here's [Visualizing Neural Network Layer Activation (Tensorflow Tutorial)](https://medium.com/@awjuliani/visualizing-deep-learning-with-t-sne-tutorial-and-video-e7c59ee4080c)